# Batch File That Finds Name of Latest file & Imports it

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have MS DOS command that runs a program and imports a file in to the program, the issue is that the file is generated in to a specific folder and named using the date/time etc, therefore the name is always different. So I need the command to be able to find the name of the latest file and use it within the command to import.
Thanks!

Comment: the commad might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

This will get the name of the latest file in the directory the batch file is run from. You can add the path after dir if you want to get the latest file from a directory other than that which it is ran. Add your command at the end of the batch file and use the batch file in place of that command from the command line.

```
 @echo off
 setlocal
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od /a-d') do set latest=%%a
 echo Latest File: %latest%
 Command <any switches> %latest%
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear the folder out, into another so that it is empty. Then make your batch file copy any file it has just processed to that folder also. That way there is only ever one file in the folder, which is easy enough to deal with using a `for ... in ()` command.